# can you drop "I was" in a sentence?

Tags: pronunciation

I am watching Friends TV series season6 episode 22, there is a scene  when Monica comes home and says:

> "I bought groceries, I was just gonna make you dinner"

but I can't hear "I was" at all, I slowed down the speed and watched it for thousands of times and I still just hear: "I bought groceries, just gonna make you dinner" is it possible that she really drops "I was".. and I know about connected speech or reduction and linking ..if she is reducing or linking, can somebody tell me how exactly she is doing that? And how can I hear it? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible she dropped "I was." If you listened to it carefully once, and didn't hear it, I'd say it wasn't there.

Here's another common *spoken* expression:

> Gotta run!

Spoken English often uses sentence fragments and other shortcuts. Not to mention assumptions based on context.

In the example I gave, it could be short for "I've got to run," "You've got to run," "We've got to run," or "They've got to run." Context would indicate the intended meaning.

In general, spoken English is far less about technical accuracy than it is about conveyed meaning. Many things can be said in a way that they would never be written, yet still be understood. In speech, especially *casual* speech, that's all that really matters.

Comment: then is it possible to drop "did" in "did you see a little mouse?" because i had the same things with hearing "did"...is there a rule for dropping and how can i be sure  that something  is dropped or i can't hear it ?

Comment: @armand It's certainly not "a rule," and I wouldn't recommend that you do so, but it's quite possible. "You there?" "Got it?" "See it?" "A mouse!"